# Клонирование приложения (.apk)

Tags: java, android, apk

Доброго времени суток. Поступила инфа о возможности клонировать приложение (.apk). Связано это с механизмом частичного обновления - добавки новых классов в имеющийся декс. Но рабочего алгоритма добиться так и не удалось. Так же известно, что схема работает без рута на 90% устройств и связано с правкой приложений. Хотелось бы услышать идеи/варианты/решения, хоть что-нибудь  :)

Comment: Можете конкретнее цель вашего клонирования указать?